# AngularJS ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

AngularJS state machine extension ui-router declares a directive that converts routes with attribute `ui-sref` into `href` paths and populates it with requested variables. Is there a way to access the same route parser from a scope?

**Update**

I am looking for a hopefully built-in yet undocumented resolver (or a way to get the same outcome) that gives the path to a named argument. In the spirit of a named route:

```
<a ui-sref="management.person({personId: 1})" />
```

Which matches a route

```
$stateProvider.state('management', {
  url: '/absolute/part'
});

$stateProvider.state('management.person', {
  url: '/relative/part/:personId'
});
```

and outputs `#/absolute/part/relative/part/1` - and in case I switch to use `!` fragment, all the URLs are converted. Directive itself does this already, but its arguments cannot be constructed dynamically.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/ee292fdfa62c348b2198a71edba3507199e78b81/release/angular-ui-router.js

Line 3432 is where that directive is declared. You might be able to access it through `ui.router.state.uiSref`, passing in custom link options, but I've never seen it done.

Are you looking to run, essentially, the link function programmatically?

Comment: This determines now the rest of the approach. I have a role-based user privileges and I would like to set e.g. the navigation links in controllers rather than hiding and revealing them in a HTML template, which is the design choice ui-router directs to if I want to use its directives.

Comment: In that case, the route I would use would be setting navigation etc through `$rootScope` variables modified in a permissions service. Maybe explore that? It's all still presentation-layer security, but I think you might find it less trouble to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It still exactly doesn't tackle the convenience of dynamic URL paths that ui-router gives. I *could* live with a CSS class toggling even though it hurts me a bit. And since this system is all API based when passing any information, API itself has to be the bulletproofed part, since all AngularJS code is anyway world readable, being just a set of static JS files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ui-router provides several services in an API that you can use to do things this. Try one of these examples:

From http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

```
var url = $state.href('about-person', {
    person: "bob"
});
```

From http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouter

```
var url = $urlRouter.href(new UrlMatcher("/about/:person"), {
    person: "bob"
});
```

These two patterns convert state names and URL templates into fully formatted URLs. There are additional API calls available as well.

Comment: Yes, I found this as well, but it doesn't work as `ui-sref` does. `ui-sref` eats named routes (which accepts stuff like this: `management.person({personId: 1})` and outputs a `href` that matches a named route), here I would need to define the route path and set arguments, which isn't one bit better than creating the URL by hand by setting the arguments.

Comment: Your question asked for "a call that gives the path to a named argument." The above code does precisely that. Please clarify your question with a specific example of what you're trying to do. If you're just objecting to the UrlMatcher and path, and want to use a state name - that's just the example. Try `$state.href()` if you want to supply a state name and params instead of a path. All of these are documented in the URL I supplied above.

Comment: I just did so, actually. If `$state.href` accepts named states, that would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Here's the direct URL for that reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options

Comment: Indeed it does. This answer, though, answers now an outdated question after my updates. If you wish to create a new answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Stack prefers clarifications to keep the noise down. See if the above is useful.

Answer (score 5):

As of March 2015 I got `'UrlMatcher is not defined'` for Chad Robinson's answer. But I succeeded by injecting `$urlMatcherFactory` and replace urlParams in a ui-router template url.

```
$urlMatcherFactory.compile("/about/:person").format({
    person: "bob"
})
```